# Canonical no-www URLs with Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, canonical-link, no-www

What do you think about this solution? The idea is to make the no-www version as the canonical one. So we simply strip out the 'www.' from the request url:

```
!= '<link rel="canonical" href="' + request.url.gsub(/www\./, '') + '" />'
```

Any problems?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Rack Canonical Host](https://github.com/tylerhunt/rack-canonical-host#readme). I think it does exactly what you are looking for.